# My laptop CD-DVD disc drive (reader) not displayed in "My Computer" and does not open when try to open

Tags: windows-8, dvd, compact-disc, optical-drive

I have used my DELL 3521 laptop running on Windows 8 Professional for 1 year now. But it stopped showing **CD-DVD reader** in ***My Computer*** (on pressing WINDOWS+E). It is not working. I don't know what happened because it used to work fine without any problem. When I press the eject button it does not even sign of working. I thought of **re-installing windows** but I will loose many files and programs. How can I fix this without re-installing windows?

Comment: Does the device appear in device manager? If not ejecting that would point to a hardware issue.  Have you attempted to remove the drive to check for physical issues?

Comment: I can say without a shadow of any doubt, reinstalling Windows, will **NOT** solve this problem.  What you describe is not a software problem its a hardware problem.

Comment: @DaveM it does not appear in the device manager and that's what made me think it is a software problem.

Comment: @Ramhound is there any way I can use to check if the problem is hardware-related?

Comment: The simplest way would be to replace the reader and see if the new device works.

Answer (score 2):

Well the fact that it doesn't open when you press the open button indicates a power problem or something physically wrong since even if the data cable is disconnected, the drive should still open when pressing the button.

Check that power is indeed going to the drive. If it is, then chances are great that something is wrong inside the drive.